# How Transfer the database from LocalDB to Sql server using EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, localdb

By default my database was setup to Localdb, and now that I finished my project I want to move my database to sql server.

I read many articles online on how to do it, but none of the solutions provided online solved my issue since I used EF and EF would always complain or it would not be able to find the database after I changed the connection string.

Below you can see my connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>

    <add name="DataContextEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=zzzz;initial catalog=DataContext;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

    <add name="DataContextEntities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=DataContext;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And here it is my EF tag:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to install SQL Server first. Then create your database, populate it then change the connection string to point at it

Comment: is your database available in SQL?

Comment: I did that but there is something I need to do with the entity framework and I am not sure what ..
Inside here <entityFramework>........</entityFramework>

Comment: So - you have an EDMX model for the database right?  I'm guessing database first - so you'd need to create the database on the new server first, and then publish the EDMX to it.

Comment: No it is code first.

Comment: Once you have a running sql server you need to change your connection string to point at it. Please post the connection strings your tried, the _exact_ error message. Take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for examples. Here's an article on deploying code-first implementations: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases